# Linking a textview with an arraylist and change text when event occurs

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview, swipe

So basically I have textview, I want the textview to be attached to ArrayList of strings, and then the text will changed based on swipe event.!

How can I make the textview show the next element text when I swipe left or right and when I swipe again it will the show the next element text and so on..! 
and when it reaches the final element it will loop back again to the first element.!?

I've tried code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634823/android-show-hide-textview-using-swipe-left-to-right) for swipe, but I don't know how show texts from ArrayList..!?

Can this be accomplished..!?

Comment: I can't understand you. What ArrayList? Is it a ListView or a RecyclerView? Show an image.

Comment: I meant a normal ArrayList of strings..! I'll edit that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
@Override
public void onSwipeRight() {
super.onSwipeRight();
if(counter == arraylist.size()}{
      counter =0;
}
 textview.setText(arraylist.get(counter));
 counter++;
});
```

Try this.

Comment: cool, but one problem, the last element in the array was skipped?

Comment: My bad , Remove "-1" from if condition ..!will it help right ?